# Refactoring advice - Ruby 101 - using multiple nested if-then's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, refactoring

What the prescribed best practice for refactoring the following?

```
def has_thing?
  if things and things[:something] and things[:something][:else] and things[:something][:else][:matters]
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

I basically want to return true if `things[:something][:else][:matters]` is not nil, but `return true if things[:something][:else][:matters]` fails when `things` is nil or... `things[:something]` is nil with e.g. `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`.

I could wrap it all it a `begin...rescue..end` and return false if an exception is thrown, but that doesn't seem right either!

Comment: `and` is not the same as `&&`. What you are doing is wrong. You need to use `&&`.

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions! (ATM you have 0 out of 9)

Answer (score 4):

Two options I might suggest:

```
def has_thing?
  !!(things && things[:something] && things[:something][:else] && things[:something][:else][:matters])
end
```

Or for more readable

```
def has_thing?
  return false unless things
  return false unless things[:something]
  return false unless things[:something][:else]
  return false unless things[:something][:else][:matters]
  true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that this code:

```
if something
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

is completely equivalent to:

```
!!something
```

Or directly `something` if it's a boolean. Note also that's not idiomatic to explicitly write `return` when you are writing the last expression of a method.

Also, try to avoid repeating checks in a hash. I'd recommend [ick](http://ick.rubyforge.org/)'s *maybe*.

Also, in you *core_ext* module you could have this method:

```
class Object
  def to_bool
    !!self
  end
end
```

At the end, the code looks much more concise and declarative:

```
def has_thing?
  things[:something].maybe[:else].maybe[:matters].to_bool
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

```
def has_thing?
  !! things.try(:[], :something).try(:[], :else).try(:[], :matters)
end
```

A more verbose version using `Hash#fetch`:

```
def has_thing?
  true if things &&
          things.fetch(:something){ return false }.
                 fetch(:else)     { return false }.
                 [:matters]
end
```

Comment: Here are the [Rails docs for `try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try).

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with:

```
def has_thing?
  !!(
    things &&
    things[:something] &&
    things[:something][:else] &&
    things[:something][:else][:matters]
  )
end
```

Being able to quickly understand what code is doing is important for long-term code maintenance.

Vertical alignment makes it easy for us to quickly scan lines that are changing and see what is new.

Answer (score 0):

There are various solutions to this problem. One is to use[andand](https://github.com/raganwald/andand). Your code would become something like:

```
def has_things?
  things.andand[:something].andand[:else].andand[:matters]
end
```

While not terribly pretty, it would solve the problem.